# Android listview search and fastscroll

Tags: android, search, listview, fastscroll

I fairly new to programming for the Android platform and have some question about howto add a search box and fastscroll to the listview of my app.

I have used the code of [Jeff Sharkey](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/) to add a listview with headers to my app.
This is working great but I like to have a searchbox add the top and fastscroll enabled, I have tried some tutorials on this but I can't get it to work.

And how can I get the clicked item? I used setOnItemClickListener but this isn't working.

Can anybody help me out please?

Thx, Daniël

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using MergeAdapter by Mark Murphy

https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge

It allows you to addViews not just text as in case of Jeff Sharkey's version. So you can add your buttons as views in between and still use a single list.

Hope it helps !!!

Comment: I've found a other section list: http://code.google.com/p/android-section-list/ but I still have the same question. I like to add a search and scrollview function. I want this one because it has a sticky header. Can you help me?

Comment: Daniel sorry i dont follow. you want a scrollview in a list?